# What is the biggest difference between evm-enabled blockchains built on top of the substrate?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, pallet, evm

What is the biggest difference between evm-enabled blockchains built on top of the substrate

Comment: Substrate is important and special in its outstanding features and characteristics. In the self-answer section, you also mentioned it quite fully. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Substrate** (Substrate) is a modular framework that allows building various blockchains based on libraries with custom or pre-made components.

And Substrate is used for Polkadot's blockchain building framework. It provides developers with a variety of tools to design their custom blockchains for a variety of possible applications. The blockchains can then be launched independently or integrated in Polkadot's network of shards, or "Parachains". Substrate is one of the three core technologies that make up the future Web3 vision including Parity Ethereum (Eth 1.0 as well as Serenity), Parity Substrate, and Polkadot.

Differences and outstanding features:
Fast and efficient database
Modular P2P Stack
The consensus layer is subject to change
Queue transaction confirmation
Flexible runtime library
Optimized for lightweight applications.

Outstanding Features
Fast and efficient database
Modular P2P Stack
The consensus layer is subject to change
Queue transaction confirmation
Flexible runtime library
Optimized for lightweight applications.
Outstanding Features
Outstanding Substrate Structure and Compatibility

Notable structure:
Architected on WebAssembly;
Industry Standard Networking Libp2p;
Highly scalable;
Rust-based primary implementation for speed and reliability Javascript secondary implementation for development
Wasm WebAssembly interpreter, written in Rust.

Compatibility:
Not every blockchain is suitable for every network. With Substrate, you can mix and match features to fit your project's needs.

Smart Contract WebAssembly
Allow multi-chain level
State and transactions are encrypted.
Limited asynchronous call options.
Locked account level.
Governance tools and methods such as stakeholder referendums, approval voting, and qualified abstentions.